When an EmailMessage is created, is an Account record modified?
I’m experiencing some issues with the "Unable to obtain exclusive access" error when agents send an email to a Contact (which is linked to the Case’s Account).
To replicate this error in a dev org, I updated a field in the Account (using the Developer Console) and then sent an EmailMessage to the Contact (which is linked to the Account of the Case and the update I performed in the Developer Console). I encountered the same error:

My question is: Why does Salesforce need to obtain exclusive access to an Account record when sending an email?
An important detail is that I created a fresh playground org and was able to reproduce the same error, so this is not caused by any of my custom automation.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

I wanna say that this is somehow related to "Salesforce locks parent records when executing triggers on child records", but I think that's generally for master-detail relationships with a rollup on the parent record. Salesforce has done some odd things with standard objects though...
